# Find the tangent to a function

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

Find the tangent to this

$\displaystyle y={1 \over x+3}$

it's crossing the point $(-2,1)$

I have drawn the lines but I can't calculate it

Comment: I formated your question in $\LaTeX$ please check that I didn't alter the meaning of what you asked.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(calculus) you can find lots of pictures of tangents here.

Comment: @Git Gud no you didn't. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expected to solve this graphically, you can extend your lines to the x and y axes and calculate the gradient from the two axis intercepts. The intercepts should be integers, so your graphs can be quite precise in this problem :)

If you draw the graphs of $y=\dfrac{1}{x+3}$ and drew a tangent line at the point $(−2,1)$, you would see that the tangent crosses the y-intercept at -1 and the x-intercept at -1. From this, you get the gradient of this tangent as -1 and the equation of the tangent becomes $y=−x−1$.

EDIT: Added stuff from my comment below, though it now gives the answer away...

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Gid Gud You mentioned 'drawn the lines' which got me thinking that you have a graph drawn. If you draw the graphs of $y = \dfrac{1}{x+3}$ and drew a tangent line at the point $(-2,1)$, you would see that the tangent crosses the y-intercept at -1 and the x-intercept at -1. From this, you get the gradient of this tangent as -1 and the equation of the tangent becomes $y = -x - 1$. I think post did address your question.

Comment: Please note that I wasn't the one asking the question. The OP did mention he draw the lines, but I think that's just him telling the community what he tried. I don't think he's expected to  solve it graphically.

Comment: @GitGud And why not, may I ask? The tag calculus was not in the original post, and solving graphically are considered solutions as well.

Comment: As it is clear by my last comment, it is just my opinion. I can't explain why I think he's not supposed to solve it graphically, it's just the vibe I get from the question. Either way *solving graphically* is not solving at all (even if it happens to be what he's asked to do)!

Comment: @GitGud Well, okay, if that method is the method asked for but not the suitable method for this question, I wonder why exams always put 'Read the instructions carefully', and I'm really sorry for the kid who thinks that his methods are better than the methods he is asked to used, even if his method is better/easier.

Comment: @Jerry I'm supposed to do it both graphically and calculate it

Comment: @Jerry So apparently you're right. I can't remove my downvote unless you edit the answer, and I do think it needs editing. I think you should add more stuff to the answer, namely what you said  in a comment above.

Comment: I still havent got any clue of how I can calculate it

Comment: To get the equation of the tangent to the curve via calculation, you need to get the gradient of the curve at the point specified. To get the gradient of the curve, you differentiate the curve with respect to x and put the x-coordinate in it. $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{1}{(x+3)^2}$. Put $x = -2$ and you should get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -1$. This means that the gradient of the curve (and that of the tangent) is -1 there. You have the gradient, and a point on the line (-2,1). This should be sufficient to get the equation of the gradient!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The slope of the tangent line at the point $(-2, 1)$ is equal to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(-2)$.

Comment: Can you explaine that further?

Comment: Since $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-1}{(x + 3)^2}$, the slope of the tangent line should be equal to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(-2) = -1$. So the required one is of the form $y = -x + c$ for some constant $c$. From the condition that the point $(-2, 1)$ on the line, $1 = -(-2) + c$ and hence $c = -1$.